# Return struct pointer from C to Python using ctypes - 32 bit python on 64 bit system

Tags: python, pointers, struct, ctypes, fftw

I'm trying to access a C function that returns a struct pointer using ctypes. I'm using 32 bit ipython from EPD. I'm on a 64 bit CentOS machine, but I have to use 32 bit Python, because the shared lib is 32 bit. When I try to get the struct pointer, I get a segmentation fault. I don't need to access the struct fields, because I'm only using the struct as input to another C function. The code looks something like this.

```
from ctypes import *

libfoo = CDLL("libfoo.so")

func1 = libfoo.func1
func2 = libfoo.func2

func1.restype = c_void_p

obj = func1() # This is where it stops with segfault

func2 (data, obj)
```

---

C Code

---

```
typedef struct
{
    int int1;
    int int2;
    float float1;
    float *arr;
    fftwf_plan fft;
} mystruct;


mystruct *func1(void)
{
    mystruct *bar = (mystruct *) malloc (sizeof(mystruct));

    bar->int1 = 1;
    bar->int2 = 2;
    bar->float1 = 1.0;
    ....

    bar->arr = (float *) fftwf_malloc (sizeof(float) * (FFT_LEN + 2));
    bar->fft = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d (FFT_LEN, ch->arr, (fftwf_complex *)ch->arr, FFTW_MEASURE);

    return bar;
}

void func2 (float *data, mystruct *bar)
{
    ....
}
```

I tried creating a ctypes struct object as well, but still got a segfault. If possible, I'd like to simply pass the pointer across to func2, without having to create a ctypes Structure. I've read several posts with similar questions, but none of them really match.

Comment: Where is it segfaulting?  Before control reaches `func1`?  Inside `func`?  During the return from `func1` back into Python?

Comment: I've already tested the C code using a C main function, without errors. So the segfault isn't occurring in the C code. In pdb, the segfault occurs right at the call to func1. A gdb stacktrace doesn't show much. It just says that the segfault occurred at n1fv_8 in libfoo.so. "nm libfoo.so | grep n1fv_8" returns "T fftwf_codelet_n1fv_8_sse2."

Comment: According to http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/julia_vpre4.22.12/julia/external/fftw-3.3-single/dft/simd/common/Makefile "n1fv_<n> is a hard-coded FFTW_FORWARD FFT of size <n>, using SIMD."

Comment: Commenting out the line that calculates the fftw plan in the C code eliminates the segfault. So why doesn't fftw work when the function is called from ctypes?

Comment: Update: Changing from FFTW_MEASURE to FFTW_ESTIMATE solved the problem. Of course, that's not a real solution. I guess I just don't understand the inner workings of ctypes well enough, but why would the code work fine executed from C, but not using ctypes?

Comment: The line you commented out is probably corrupting the stack.  Anything can happen including working in C and failing in Python.